# No drop down is shown when using columns.ForeignKey in kendo grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

In kendo grid, when I use columns.ForeignKey, I am not getting a drop down. I actually         need a drop down with the list of countries. Where do I go wrong!! Pls help. I have included the model,view and the controller.

MatchViewModel:

```
  public short MatchID { get; set; }      
  public virtual Country Country1 { get; set; }
```

CountryModel:

```
  public short CountryID { get; set; }       
  public string Name { get; set; }
```

This is my view

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FootballPredictor.Models.Match        ViewModel>)ViewData["matches"])       
        .Name("grid")       
        .Columns(columns =>   
        {   
     columns.Bound(m => m.MatchID).Width(50);      
     columns.ForeignKey(m => m.Country1.Name, (IEnumerable)ViewBag.Countries, dataFieldText:     "Name", dataFieldValue: "CountryID");       
     columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(150);    
        }) .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())      
       .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))       
       .Editable(e => e.DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Are you sure to delete?"))      
       .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:280px;" })      
       .Pageable()      
       .Scrollable()      
       .DataSource(ds => ds     
       .Server()      
       .PageSize(10)     
       .Model(m =>      
       {      
           m.Id(p => p.MatchID);      
           m.Field(p => p.MatchID).Editable(false);       
     m.Field(p => p.Country1).Editable(true);      
      })      
      .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Match"))      
       .Create(update => update.Action("Create", "Match"))      
       .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "Match"))      
       .Destroy(update => update.Action("Delete", "Match"))     
    ))
```

Controller:

In controller I am assigning List to ViewBag.Countries.I have checked that I      am getting the list in ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

Try changining

```
columns.ForeignKey(m => m.Country1.Name, (IEnumerable)ViewBag.Countries, dataFieldText:     "Name", dataFieldValue: "CountryID");
```

to

```
columns.ForeignKey(m => m.Country1.Name, (IEnumerable<Country>)ViewBag.Countries, "Name", "CountryID");
```

assuming the Enumerable is a collection of `Country`

Comment: This won't work as the parameter does not take a non-generic version of IEnumerable.